# SQL update statement not updating on phpmyadmin record

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

Hi been working on this for a while now but can't seem to figure out why it won't update.
I have written the statement but when it is ran it doesn't update the record at all but i cannot see what is wrong.

```
$query = ("INSERT INTO tbldvd(Title, Certificate, Director, Genre, Synopsis, RentalAmount, BeingRented) VALUES('$Title','$Certification','$Director','$Genre','$Synopsis','$Price','$Rented') WHERE DVDID= ".$ID."");
```

Is my query, which when ran I get the error

```
ERROR 404: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO tbldvd(Title, Certificate, Director, Genre, Synopsis, RentalAmount, BeingRented) VALUES ('Secret Life Of Walter Mitty','18','Ben Stiller','Family','Day Dreamer','5.00','No') WHERE DVDID= 3 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE DVDID= 3' at line 1
```

Already tried the update command to get the same issue

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tbldvd SET Title=[$Title],Certificate=[$Certification],Director=[$Director],Genre=[$Genre],Synopsis=[$Synopsis],RentalAmount=[$Price],BeingRented=[$Rented] WHERE DVDID = $ID");
```

Where i got the error

```
ERROR 404: Could not able to execute You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Secret Life Of Walter Mitty],Certificate=[18],Director=[Ben Stiller],`Genre' at line 1
```

Comment: INSERT has no WHERE clause. (A new row is inserted into the table.) Use UPDATE to update a row's columns.

Comment: what do you want insert or update ? your query written for  insert not for update

Answer (score -1):

you must use `UPDATE` syntax. see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Already tried the update command to get the same issue

$query = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `tbldvd` SET `Title`=[$Title],`Certificate`=[$Certification],`Director`=[$Director],`Genre`=[$Genre],`Synopsis`=[$Synopsis],`RentalAmount`=[$Price],`BeingRented`=[$Rented] WHERE DVDID = $ID");

Where i got the error 

ERROR 404: Could not able to execute You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Secret Life Of Walter Mitty],`Certificate`=[18],`Director`=[Ben Stiller],`Genre' at line 1

Comment: @Ollie, copy that comment into your question instead! (Note the missing single quotes... compare INSERT and UPDATE attempts...)